# Python and popup windows

Tags: python, csv, popup, window, keypress

I have searched for days and tried too many incorrect solutions. I have a python script that used to upload a csv file to a website. The website has added a popup box that must be addressed before the upload can begin. How do I detect that popup box and simulate an "OK" click? I have check and rechecked that the file is correct (it will upload properly if done manually). Script is hosted on GoDaddy and was a P.. I.. T.. A.. to get host to run.I am not that familiar with python but didn't think it would be this difficult. Yes I tried:

```
from evdev import uinput, ecodes as e

with uinput.UInput() as ui:
     ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_ENTER, 1)
     ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_ENTER, 0)
     ui.syn()
```

and it does not work! I found this smippit but it doesn't work either:

```
import thread
import time

def keypress():
    global char
    char = chr(13)
```

Comment: Which website is it. Are you in control of that website? I'd like to see the upload form. The snippet you pasted just gets the character for enter but then does nothing with it.

Comment: How are you uploading the csv? Are you interacting with a browser or using urllib/requests directly? If there's no browser, then there's no javascript and no button to click ;)

Comment: yes the script uses urllib, urllib2, and cookielib The script creates the csv product file and used to upload it to the merchant website. The upload script is to long to post. The main script is run from a php file on godaddy